# Python - copying specific files from a list into a new folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, copy-paste, shutil

I am trying to get my program to read a list of names from a file (say .txt), then search for those in a selected folder and copy and paste those files to another selected folder. My program runs without errors but does not do anything:

**Code - updated:**

```
import os, shutil
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
folderPath = filedialog.askdirectory()
destination = filedialog.askdirectory()

filesToFind = []
with open(filePath, "r") as fh:
    for row in fh:
        filesToFind.append(row.strip())

#Added the print statements below to check that things were feeding correctly
print(filesToFind)
print(folderPath)
print(destination)

#The issue seems to be with the copy loop below:    
for target in folderPath:
    if target in filesToFind:
        name = os.path.join(folderPath,target)
        print(name)
        if os.path.isfile(name):
            shutil.copy(name, destination)
        else:
            print ("file does not exist", name)
        print(name)
```

Update - runs without errors but does not move any files.

Comment: You want `row.strip()` instead of `row.strip`.  Note the parentheses.

Comment: `for files in folderPath:` isn't doing what you think. You want `for file in os.listdir(folderPath):` instead.

Comment: I changed that to `filesToFind.append(rowstrip())` and `for file in os.listdir(folderPath): if file in filesToFind:` but got the same result (no result)

Comment: Update the question to contain your most recent code.

Comment: updated. Apologies still learning the best practices for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that works -

```
import os
import shutil
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
folderPath = filedialog.askdirectory()
destination = filedialog.askdirectory()

# First, create a list and populate it with the files

# you want to find (1 file per row in myfiles.txt)

filesToFind = []
with open(filePath, "r") as fh:
    for row in fh:
        filesToFind.append(row.strip())

# Had an issue here but needed to define and then reference the filename variable itself
for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
    if filename in filesToFind:
        filename = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
        shutil.copy(filename, destination)
    else:
        print("file does not exist: filename")
```

Note - Need to included the file extension in the file being read. Thanks to @lenik and @John Gordon for the help getting there! Time to refine it to make it more userfriendly

Comment: last line should be: print( filename, "is not copied")

Answer (score 3):

The last part of your program might work better this way:

```
for file in files:
    if file in filesToFind:
        name = os.path.join( folderPath, file )
        if os.path.isfile( name ) :
            shutil.copy( name, destination)
        else :
            print 'file does not exist', name
```

Otherwise it's pretty much unknown where you copy your files from, current folder, maybe, and why did you need to input `folderPath` earlier, if you don't use it.

btw, `file` is a reserved word in python, I'd recommend to use another name for your variable, that does not coincide with python reserved words.

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a shot when I get to work in the morning. I was using `folderPath` earlier to get the folder I want the program to loop through and look for the files in. Looking back at it now I see your point that I was not calling it anywhere.

Thanks for the file heads up I will change that as well.

Comment: Also realized I threw the label in the wrong spot. The top code set is what was the updated code. Originally, I was not calling it but in the updated code I was with `for file in os.listdir(folderPath)`. Thoughts on why that might not work?

Comment: @JasonLeach `os.listdir()` gives you just file names (without path). you have to supply path to be able to copy or open or do anything with the files. hence, `os.path.join( path, name)`

Comment: I tested it this morning and with no result. I added `print(name)` after the `name = ` statement but it tells me name is not defined. thought on how I could print that out so I can attempt to debug?

Comment: @JasonLeach please, show the code, I don't believe `name` could be empty right after the assignment.

Comment: @JasonLeach `print ("file does not exist" & name)` -- you need a comma `,` instead of ampersand `&` here

Comment: Code updated - I tried it in two places (see above) and in both cases it says it is not defined. Is it possible that the `os.path.join` needs a `\` between `folderPath, target' ? Sorry new to `os.` and python in general.

Comment: @JasonLeach `print name` statement should have the same indentation as the previous `name =` line, otherwise it won't work. indentation is quite important in python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176815/discussion-between-jason-leach-and-lenik).

Answer (score 2):

Your last section has a problem.

```
for file in os.listdir(folderPath): 
    for file in files:
        if file in filesToFind:
            shutil.copy(file, destination)
```

The first `for` loops over each filename in the directory, which is perfectly understandable.

The second `for` is an error, because `files` does not exist.  What did you intend it to do?

Comment: I think I thought I was trying to say: "for each `file` (renamed `target`) name in `filesToFind` list from `filePath`, look in `folderPath` folder for the file names and copy and paste them to the `destination` folder."  
In regards to `files` I wanted to look at all the `file` names in `filePath` and loop through the folder. If that makes sense? I removed it and updated the code above - question assuming the `for file in` loop is correct, should it be `for file in filePath` or `for file in folderPath`?